# Semantic-release is not getting installed and asking specific Node version which I can't update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, semantic-release

The "semantic-release" package is preventing the installation of "node_modules" in my React Native project. Despite searching for a solution, I couldn't locate the package causing the issue. This might be due to compatibility conflicts or other configuration problem.
I am not allowed to update Node.js.

Please find the error image in the link
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3FLt.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "enter image description here"? What exactly is the error message?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IngoSteinke please find the image in above link

Comment: Hi @AkarshKR and welcome to StackOverflow! For future question and answer, please inform about how to ask and format a good question, using inline code and images, quotations, and providing minimal reproducible examples, to improve accessibility for the community. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @IngoSteinke thank you, next time i will definitely post questions and answers in a structured way

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exactly what the error message says, but instead of `node_modules`, the problem is your current Node version is not what they want (v16.20.0 vs newer than v18.0.0).

To make it happy, you will need up update your Node version to >v18.0.0

You can either do that by going to the official NodeJS download page to download and install the recommended version `v18.17.1 LT`. Link: https://nodejs.org/en, or use Node Version Manager (nvm) to change the Node version in your session at your will. Link: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I'm facing limitations within the project I'm working on that prevent me from updating Node.js.

Comment: @AkarshKR If that is the case, you can also use the older version of `semantic-release` so the requirement NodeJS version requirement meets your need. For example, v17.4.7 only requires you to have a NoderJS version of v10.19 or higher according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-release/v/17.4.7